How to emulate NFC FeliCa tag with specific service code and block data?
I'm working on a project to emulate an NFC tag with specific service codes and block data in Python using nfcpy. My goal is to read a card, capture its data (service codes, blocks, and content), and then emulate this tag with the exact data structure so that a reader would recognize it as the original card.
The code runs without errors, and I can see output messages like “tag activated,” but the reader still doesn’t recognize the emulated tag as it does with the original card. Additionally, I am unable to correctly set the service code in a way that allows for proper data reading and writing based on the blocks retrieved from the original card.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I can successfully read data from the card, including service codes and block data, using nfcpy.

Based on the data I captured, I set up an emulation environment using nfcpy on a USB NFC reader (Sony RC-S380).

I tried adding services with tag.add_service() and defining ndef_read and ndef_write functions to provide block-level data.


I can successfully read data from the card, including service codes and block data, using nfcpy. Based on the data I captured, I set up an emulation environment using nfcpy on a USB NFC reader (Sony RC-S380). I tried adding services with tag.add_service() and defining ndef_read and ndef_write functions to provide block-level data.
Here is a sample of my code so far:
    import nfc
    import struct
    
    ndef_data_area = bytearray(64 * 16)
    ndef_data_area[0] = 0x10  # NDEF mapping version '1.0'
    ndef_data_area[1] = 12    # Number of blocks that may be read at once
    ndef_data_area[2] = 8     # Number of blocks that may be written at once
    ndef_data_area[4] = 63    # Number of blocks available for NDEF data
    ndef_data_area[10] = 1    # NDEF read and write operations are allowed
    ndef_data_area[14:16] = struct.pack('>H', sum(ndef_data_area[0:14]))  # Checksum
    
    def ndef_read(block_number, rb, re):
        if block_number < len(ndef_data_area) / 16:
            first, last = block_number * 16, (block_number + 1) * 16
            return ndef_data_area[first:last]
    
    def ndef_write(block_number, block_data, wb, we):
        global ndef_data_area
        if block_number < len(ndef_data_area) / 16:
            first, last = block_number * 16, (block_number + 1) * 16
            ndef_data_area[first:last] = block_data
            return True
    
    def on_startup(target):
        idm, pmm, sys = '03FEFFE011223344', '01E0000000FFFF00', '12FC'
        target.sensf_res = bytearray.fromhex('01' + idm + pmm + sys)
        target.brty = "212F"
        return target
    
    def on_connect(tag):
        print("tag activated")
        
        tag.add_service(0x1A88, ndef_read, ndef_write)
        tag.add_service(0x000B, ndef_read, lambda: False)
        return True
    
    with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb:054c:06c1') as clf:
        while clf.connect(card={'on-startup': on_startup, 'on-connect': on_connect}):
            print("tag released")

My questions are:

How can I correctly emulate an NFC tag with specific service codes and block data so a reader interprets it exactly as the original card?
Is there something specific to nfcpy that I’m missing when setting service codes or block data that could affect the emulation?
Are there better libraries or methods to achieve FeliCa tag emulation, particularly if nfcpy has limitations in service code handling?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
追記:
I am trying to implement the following data in the program.
　connected
System 8688 (unknown)
Area 0000--FFFE
System FE00 (Common Area)
Area 0000--FFFE
  Area 1A80--1AFF
    Area 1A81--1AFF
      Random Service 106: write with key & read w/o key (0x1A88 0x1A8B)
       0000: 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 00 00 30 31 |010000000000..01|
       0001: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |... ............|
       0002: 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 30 32 34 30 34 30 31 |0000000020240401|
       0003: 32 30 33 33 30 33 33 31 63 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 |20330331c0000000|
      Area 1B00--1B3F
      Area 1B01--1B3F
        Random Service 108: write with key & read with key (0x1B08 0x1B0A)
        Area 1B40--1B7F
        Area 1B41--1B7F
          Random Service 109: write with key & read with key (0x1B48 0x1B4A)
          Area 42C0--42FF
          Area 42C1--42FF
            Random Service 267: write with key & read with key (0x42C8 0x42CA)
            Area 4300--433F
            Area 4301--433F
              Random Service 268: write with key & read with key (0x4308 0x430A)
              Area 4340--437F
              Area 4341--437F
                Random Service 269: write with key & read w/o key (0x4348 0x434B)
                 0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                 *     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                 0002: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                Area 50C0--50FF
                Area 50C1--50FF
                  Random Service 323: write with key & read w/o key (0x50C8 0x50CB)
                   0000: 00 00 21 12 08 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |..!.............|
                   0001: 01 00 22 12 26 00 06 49 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |..".&..I........|
                   0002: 00 00 01 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |...h............|
                   0003: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                   *     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                   0005: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
                  Cyclic Service 323: write with key & read w/o key (0x50CC 0x50CF)
                   0000: 20 22 12 13 19 21 35 05 00 00 10 00 09 90 00 00 | "...!5.........|
                   0001: 20 22 12 12 13 14 59 05 00 00 93 00 10 00 00 00 | "....Y.........|
                   0002: 20 22 12 10 15 08 51 05 00 00 27 00 10 93 00 00 | "....Q...'.....|
                   0003: 20 22 12 09 21 51 08 05 00 00 96 00 11 20 00 00 | "..!Q....... ..|
                   0004: 20 22 12 09 17 14 32 01 00 01 00 00 12 16 00 00 | "....2.........|
                   0005: 20 22 12 08 18 35 55 05 00 00 35 00 11 16 00 00 | "...5U...5.....|
                   0006: 20 22 12 07 17 26 18 05 00 00 74 00 11 51 00 00 | "...&....t..Q..|
                   0007: 20 22 12 06 17 51 06 05 00 03 21 00 12 25 00 00 | "...Q....!..%..|
                   0008: 20 22 12 06 14 42 30 01 00 10 00 00 15 46 00 00 | "...B0......F..|
                   0009: 20 22 12 05 20 15 35 05 00 03 21 00 05 46 00 00 | ".. .5...!..F..|
                  Purse Service 323: direct with key & decrement with key & read w/o key (0x50D0 0x50D4 0x50D7)
                   0000: de 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 70 |...............p|

the data is retrieved by this program.
import nfc


def on_connect(tag: nfc.tag.Tag) -> bool:
    print("connected")
    print("\n".join(tag.dump()))

    return True  


def on_release(tag: nfc.tag.Tag) -> None:
    print("released")


with nfc.ContactlessFrontend("usb") as clf:
    while True:
        clf.connect(rdwr={"on-connect": on_connect, "on-release": on_release})


Ndef is a standardised data format on top of various different types of NFC Tags and if you are trying to emulate the captured "service codes, blocks, and content" then trying to use a high level data format is not going to work as it will use a specific subset of what the Tag can do.
The code is only good for emulating Ndef Data on top of a Felica Tag, you are going to have to read the Felica and this reader's Datasheets to be able control the reader enough to do lower level emulation if it can (and quite often it cannot emulate everything exactly)

Thank you for your answer and explanation!

Note the NFC Forum Specification for Type 3 (Felica conforms to this) documentation does give some more technical background on how Ndef is stored, it's available without paying at https://web.archive.org/web/20210125135127/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-3-Tag_1.1.pdf
